# Containers, Smart Pointers and Templated Inherited Classes

Tags: c++, pointers, boost

I can compile some code which fills a vector of raw pointers to a base class  with pointers to a templated inherited class. But I've tried using the standard library and boost smart pointers instead of raw pointers, and the code doesn't compile. Can you explain why not?

This works:

```
vector<base*> vec
inherited<double>* elem = new inherited<double> >();
vec.push_back(elem);
```

This doesn't:

```
vector<auto_ptr<base> > vec
auto_ptr<inherited<double> >(new inherited<double> >());
vec.push_back(elem);
```

I don't really care whether or not what I'm trying to do is reasonable I'm just feeling out what's possible.

My full 60 LOC is here:
https://gist.github.com/melvyniandrag/f432140c1aa216696bb6

Don't beat me up guys I've read a bit of [C++ Templates: The Complete Guide (2002)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201734842) and some posts here, but haven't been able to expediently connect the dots.

Comment: The `auto_ptr` is deprecated and doesn't work inside containers. Use `std::unique_ptr` instead.

Comment: I tried with unique_ptr and that does not work, but shared_ptr does as mentioned below. I guess to find the reasons why these pointers behave so differently will take some reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `std::shared_ptr` and [`std::static_pointer_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast).

```
vector<shared_ptr<base> > vec;
shared_ptr<inherited<double> > elem(new inherited<double> >());
vec.push_back(static_pointer_cast<inherited<double>,base>(elem));
```